# How to retrieve the original block of memory in cAse the realloc fails?

Tags: c

As the GNU library says, the original block is unaffected in case the reallocation of memory fails using `realloc()`. If this fails it returns `NULL`. so in the call,

```
p = (struct Node *) realloc(p, sizeof(struct Node) * 100);
```

If it fails and returns `NULL`, so `p` gets assigned as `NULL`. which causes it to lose the old address also. How retrieve the old block if this happens.

Comment: `temp_p = realloc( ... ); if(temp_p) p = temp_p;` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
p = (struct Node*)realloc(p,sizeof(struct Node)* 100);
```

could simply be;

```
struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)realloc(p,sizeof(struct Node)* 100);

if(temp == NULL) {
    // do what you need to do on failure. The old block is still in p
}

p = temp;
```

Comment: Thks a lot for your reply. I would like do a small correction. We are not sure if the realloc returns the same pointer after successful reallocation. The logic u mentioned works very well if realloc fails but at the same time if it succeeds in allocating the memory by returning a different pointer ( other than p in this case) then we are left the both new block and old block , with old block no more in use. It's better to free the old block and then assign the new address to p as below,

Comment: Ie in addition to your code snippet, if((temp!=NULL)&& (temp!=p) ) { free(p); p= temp;}

Comment: If realloc returns a new block, it always free's the old one automatically, in other words you will never end up with two blocks allocated and freeing the old pointer is never necessary. In fact, it may very well break things.